# QA Touch Jira Intergration

Tags: testing, integration-testing

I have been using QA Touch tool for performing all my Testing for my SaaS application.
I am facing issue with syncing custom fields with Jira. How Can I configure a mandatory custom field created in Jira with QA Touch while creating an Issue on Jira Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Sync JIRA Cloud Custom fields to QA Touch

1. Navigate to **Project Menu** -> **Project Integration Mapping** -> **Custom Fields Settings**
2. All the JIRA Custom fields will be listed here, select and enable the field by the switch on.

**Note:** Only "String", "Number", "Array", "Option" types of Custom Fields are supported